# php and mysql query the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
  require_once 'login1.php'; 
  $connect = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
  if ($connect -> connect_error) {
      die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
  }
  else {
      echo "connected successfully.";
  }

  //selecting a database
  $connects= mysqli_connect("localhost", "debola" , "mypassword");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
      echo "Database anuoluwa selected";
  }

  $query  = "SELECT * FROM anuoluwa";  
  $result = mysqli_query($query);
  if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($connect));
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)  {
      echo 'Author: '   . mysql_result($result,$j,'author')   . '<br>';  
      echo 'Title: '    . mysql_result($result,$j,'title')    . '<br>';  
      echo 'Category: ' . mysql_result($result,$j,'category') . '<br>';  
      echo 'Year: '     . mysql_result($result,$j,'year')     . '<br>'; 
      echo 'ISBN: '     . mysqli_result($result,$j,'isbn')     . '<br><br>';
  }
?>
```

This is the part returning the errors:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM anuoluwa";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($connect));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);"
```

Parameters required which I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Why are you conecting twice? The first connection call should be sufficient, and as a plus it's using the proper object-oriented interface, not the legacy procedural one. As a plus this will avoid falling into the trap of accidentally using `mysql_result`, which is completely wrong here since it's missing the `i`.

Comment: your code is failing on too many levels.

Comment: sorry but I don't see how this question warrants an upvote

Comment: You can't use `mysql_result()` when you're using `mysqli`. All the functions have to be `mysqli_XXX`.

Comment: It looks like you just took an old script that used `mysql_XXX`, and replaced all the `mysql` functions with the same-named `mysqli` functions, without fixing the arguments properly.

Answer (score 1):

For mysqli there should be sql connection as a first argument. [Manual mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Also, mysql_result is old function, try [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead and store result in some array. Then use foreach to use data.